# How to annotate a PDF document in WPF

Tags: wpf, pdf

First I need to show a PDF File in an WPF application . It appears the only two ways are using a web control or some sort of WinForms/Com based solution using the Acrobat reader component.
Assuming I get it to show up in a UI my problem is I want to add annotations to the PDF itself. Is this even possible.

Comment: What do you mean by adding annotations to the PDF? Could you please elaborate? You have some good third party vendors out there, I like [componentone](http://www.componentone.com/SuperProducts/PdfViewerWPF/). You could also open it in an external window using acrobat reader. And you have the option of implementing a PDF parser/writer/control your self, it's a big task though.

Comment: yeah I am trying out componentone

Comment: PSPDFKit (commercial PDF SDK) can be integrated into WPF applications using CEF. https://pspdfkit.com/guides/windows/current/other-languages/cef-chromiumembeddedframework/